# Crashlytics for old Android project structure projects

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, crashlytics

I'm using Android Studio/IntelliJ 12 and the old non-Gradle Android structure.

When I try to set up my project with `Crashlytics` my imports are not working (I have connected my project to Crashlytics via the red button).

I guess without Gradle/Maven my project doesn't know where to search for the package `com.crashlytics.android`.

In the Gradle settings (of another project) I find a couple of Maven links to the Crashlytics package. But when I try to add them as a library via `Project strcture -> libraries -> add -> from Maven` I alwary get *No files could be downloaded*

Any ideas what I can do to get my old project up and running?